# passing SET commands with SQL string in Python

Tags: python, sqlplus

I can pass a sql command fine from Python, but cannot seem to combine it with a SET - I don't want headers, so SET HEADING OFF is what I'm attempting.

Here's 4 attempts that show where I'm going:

1 - Get date, but also error message:

> ```
> session = Popen(['sqlplus','-S','user/pass@ORCL'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
> sqlCommand = "SET HEADING OFF \n / \n select sysdate from dual;"
> session.communicate(sqlCommand)
> ('SP2-0103: Nothing in SQL buffer to run.\r\n\r\n09-JUL-13\r\n\r\n', '')
> ```

2 - command without SET:

> session = Popen(['sqlplus','-S','user/pass@ORCL'], stdin=PIPE,
>   stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) sqlCommand = "select sysdate from dual;"
>   session.communicate(sqlCommand)
>   ('\r\nSYSDATE\r\n---------\r\n09-JUL-13\r\n\r\n', '')

3 - tried a one-liner:

> ```
> session = Popen(['sqlplus','-S','user/pass@ORCL'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
> sqlCommand = "set heading off \select sysdate from dual;"
> session.communicate(sqlCommand)
> ('SP2-0158: unknown SET option "\\select"\r\n', '')
> ```

4 - tried to separate into two calls:

> ```
> session = Popen(['sqlplus','-S','user/pass@ORCL'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
> sqlCommand = "select sysdate from dual;"
> session.stdin.write('SET HEADING OFF')
> session.communicate(sqlCommand)
> ('SP2-0265: heading must be set ON or OFF\r\n', '')
> ```

Finally, if this is *not* the simplest way to get a value (and that's my goal - just one value back - this is not the final query), please let me know.  Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I can't test any of these, but I can see problems in them. The first one should be:

```
sqlCommand = "SET HEADING OFF \n select sysdate from dual;"
```

The error, 'nothing in SQL buffer to run', is from the `/` on its own, which tries to run the previous command, and there isn't one yet. The `SET` is not a runnable command in this context; it's an SQL*Plus client command, not a statement that needs to be processed.

The third should be:

```
sqlCommand = "set heading off \n select sysdate from dual;"
```

... which is the same as above, but this time you'd missed the `n` from the `\n` line separator.

I'm less sure about the fourth but it looks like it should be:

```
sqlCommand = "select sysdate from dual;"
session.stdin.write('SET HEADING OFF\n')
```

... again missing the newline. From the error this time it seems to be trying to run the two parts back-to-back, i.e.:

```
SET HEADING OFFselect sysdate from dual;
```

... with no gap, and 'OFFselect' is not a valid argument for `SET HEADING`, as it says. That might be the most maintainable approach, especially if you end up with several things to set and execute.

It appears you're going to get at least one set of `\r\n` back but I don't think you can do anything about that, it's just from SQL*Plus writing to `stdout`; so you'll need to strip that on the Python side, I think.